# Extracting the number at the end of a variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing the name of a variable into a javascript function onmouseover event. The variable being passed in starts with letters and ends with numbers, and I want to extract the numbers from the variable name. How can I do that?

**Example code:**

*Lets say we pass in x = abc123*

```
function(x){
    extractednumber = parseInt(x.substring(2))
    document.write(extractednumber);
}
```

EDIT: The variable name has 3 characters in front and a unknown number of digits behind.

Comment: Is your existing code not working?

Comment: Do you want to extract numbers "from the variable *name*" or from the value currently held by the variable (with that name)?

Comment: @Dogbert: Sorry `x = abc123` is the variable name I am passing in, but it did not turn out in the post

Comment: @El Ronnoco: I want to extract the number from the **variable name**, not from the value the variable is holding

Comment: Variable name is never passed into the function. Only the value is passed. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Why don't you describe what it is you're trying to do?  What you describe is, frankly, completely bizarre and almost certainly totally unnecessary.  *Why* do you want to do this?  Show the code that wants to call this function, and perhaps somebody will see where you've gone off track.

Comment: @Pointy: I know if sounds weird. What is happening here is that the name of the variable `x` is actually the `id` attribute of a form element say a checkbox, where `id="marker6"` being marker #6. Onmouseover event, the function in original post is called, which changes the image of the marker object named `marker6` to something like `/img_mouseover_6`. This is why I want to extract the digit `6` from the variable.

Comment: I solved the problem by passing in 2 variables to `function(x, x_num)` since the `id attribute` of the checkbox is dynamically created using PHP, so I already have the digit `6` separated from the varaible name `marker6`. But I still am interested in solving this problem by only passing in 1 variable.

Comment: If you're passing in the value of the "id" attribute, then you're passing in a *value*.  In other words, the "id" attribute has a string value, so ... I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetNumber(num)
{
  var numberPart = num.replace (/[^\d]/g, “”); //use only digits
  var extractednumber = parseInt(numberPart, 10);
  return extractednumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a simple regexp pattern :

```
x.match(/([0-9]*)$/)[0]
```

then you could write :

```
function(x){
    extractednumber = parseInt(x.match(/([0-9]*)$/)[0]);
    document.write(extractednumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions to parse the string:

```
if (/(\d+)$/.test(x))
  extractedNumber = parseInt(RegExp.$1, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have exactly three characters in front, and then an unknown number of digits afterward, you can just use substr.

```
function(inputString) {
    return inputString.substr(3, inputString.length);
}
```